# Как при зажатии кнопки производить постоянное выполнение действие, пока кнопка зажата в PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, анимация, qlabel, qtimer

Мне нужно, что бы при зажатии кнопки "*Влево*" или "*Вправо*" картинка двигалась без остановки пока пользователь не отпустит кнопку, мой код:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()                          # !!! +++
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)                         # !!! +++
        
        self.btn1 = QPushButton(centralWidget)
        self.btn1.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.btn1.setText("<-- Влево")
# ???                                                                 ------> v
#        self.btn1.setStyleSheet("background-color: pink; border-radius: 14px;}")
        self.btn1.setStyleSheet("background-color: pink; border-radius: 14px;")
        self.btn1.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Pusia-Bold.otf", 17, QtGui.QFont.Bold))
        self.btn1.resize(300, 150)
        self.btn1.move(100, 400)
        self.btn1.clicked.connect(lambda : self.on_clicked("Влево"))
        
        self.btn2 = QPushButton(centralWidget)
        self.btn2.setMouseTracking(True);
        self.btn2.setText("Вправо -->")
        self.btn2.setStyleSheet("background-color: pink; border-radius: 14px;")
        self.btn2.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Pusia-Bold.otf", 17, QtGui.QFont.Bold))
        self.btn2.resize(300, 150)
        self.btn2.move(500, 400)
        self.btn2.clicked.connect(lambda : self.on_clicked("Вправо"))
        
        self.lbl1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(centralWidget)
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("im.png").scaled(300, 300)
        self.lbl1.setPixmap(self.pix)
        self.lbl1.resize(300, 300)
        self.lbl1.move(300, 20)
        
        '''
        self.spinBox = QSpinBox(centralWidget)
        self.spinBox.setRange(5, 20)
        self.spinBox.setValue(7)
        self.spinBox.resize(100, 30)
        self.spinBox.move(400, 560) 
        '''
        self.num = 100 
        

    def on_clicked(self, text):
        print(f'{text}')  
        if text == "Влево":
            x, y = self.lbl1.pos().x(), self.lbl1.pos().y()
            x = x-self.num if x-self.num > 0 else 0
            self.lbl1.move(x, y)            
        elif text == "Вправо":
            x, y = self.lbl1.pos().x(), self.lbl1.pos().y()
            w = self.size().width() - self.lbl1.size().width() 
            x = x+self.num \
                if x+self.num < w else w
            self.lbl1.move(x, y) 
            
        
if __name__ == "__main__":        
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.resize(900, 600)
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант.

Обратите внимание, я поменял **`сигналы`** кнопок и добавил `QTimer`.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)
        
        self.btn1 = QPushButton(centralWidget)
        self.btn1.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.btn1.setText("<-- Влево")
        self.btn1.setStyleSheet("background-color: pink; border-radius: 14px;")
        self.btn1.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Pusia-Bold.otf", 17, QtGui.QFont.Bold))
        self.btn1.resize(300, 150)
        self.btn1.move(100, 400)
#-        self.btn1.clicked.connect(lambda : self.on_clicked("Влево"))
        
        self.btn2 = QPushButton(centralWidget)
        self.btn2.setMouseTracking(True);
        self.btn2.setText("Вправо -->")
        self.btn2.setStyleSheet("background-color: pink; border-radius: 14px;")
        self.btn2.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Pusia-Bold.otf", 17, QtGui.QFont.Bold))
        self.btn2.resize(300, 150)
        self.btn2.move(500, 400)
#-        self.btn2.clicked.connect(lambda : self.on_clicked("Вправо"))

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv         
        self.btn1.pressed.connect(lambda: self.btn_pressed('Влево'))
        self.btn1.released.connect(self.btn_released)        
        self.btn2.pressed.connect(lambda: self.btn_pressed('Вправо'))
        self.btn2.released.connect(self.btn_released)
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 
        self.lbl1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(centralWidget)
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("im.png").scaled(300, 300)
        self.lbl1.setPixmap(self.pix)
        self.lbl1.resize(300, 300)
        self.lbl1.move(300, 20)

        self.num = 5                                                 # 100  !!!
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        #Create a Timer
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.on_clicked)
        self.timer.setInterval(100)
        
        self.text = None
        
    def btn_pressed(self, text):
        self.text = text
        self.timer.start()

    def btn_released(self):
        self.timer.stop()        
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^        

    def on_clicked(self):                                      # , text=''): !!!
        print(f'{self.text}')  
        if self.text == "Влево":
            x, y = self.lbl1.pos().x(), self.lbl1.pos().y()
            x = x-self.num if x-self.num > 0 else 0
            self.lbl1.move(x, y)            
        elif self.text == "Вправо":
            x, y = self.lbl1.pos().x(), self.lbl1.pos().y()
            w = self.size().width() - self.lbl1.size().width() 
            x = x+self.num \
                if x+self.num < w else w
            self.lbl1.move(x, y) 
            
        
if __name__ == "__main__":        
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.resize(900, 600)
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]